# Stacks and Auto-layout across iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

So I'm following a set of tutorials and have come to a point where I have the app working (A simple calculator), but the UI could still be improved.

The current UI works great on phones, but when going up to an iPad, parts of the UI expand as needed, but the buttons stay at quite a small size. I have no constraints keeping the buttons small and the stack that the buttons are in do expand to fill the space.

My project files can be found here:
https://github.com/maza256/retrocalc

An image to explain is found here:
[iPhone and iPad Preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G3OW.png)

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your project I found one change that you can make.  Go to storyboard and select the buttons then click on attribues inspector. Then under control change the alingment options on the far right, which will cause your image to expand to fit the space.

[Ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa8rU.png) 
[Inspector Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJC1.png)

Sorry that i didn't catch this in my post. But you will need to click on the stack view for the top row of numbers and make sure to make the stack view settings like this.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: Update the answer to fix one other issue I noticed. Also please be sure to up vote the answer as well. Glad I could help.

Comment: Will do. I have voted the answer, unfortunately, my reputation is too low for it to count :(

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are the right size. They are not small and behave as you expect. Try to change background color:

[iPad screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCuj8.png)

The problem is that you have very small images. You have to provide .@2x and .@3x images, so you won't lost quality on iPad.

[Image assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHVNk.png)

Comment: Well they behave as expected. But I was more hoping that they would expand to fill the space.

But it makes sense about the image sizes. I didn't think of that.

Thank you.